# deselect checkboxes and select the current one using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a help/solution for this silly question as a lot of functionality written on these checkboxes so really sorry for that.

I have checkboxes ( minimum three ). User can select any checkbox but other checkboxes should be deselect and the condition to deselect other checkboxes by triggering force 'click' event on checkboxes not prop false.

Please let me know If above description is not clear enough.

( note: i can't use radio buttons for some reasons ).

again sorry for this stupid question, really appreciate your help.

```html
<div class=" tiles">

    <div class=" savingPack">
        <input type="checkbox" name="savingspack" value="savingspack6" data-add-price-month="0" data-add-price-onetime="1500" data-other-price-divs=".addons">
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-label">op - 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" savingPack">
        <input type="checkbox" name="savingspack" value="savingspack6" data-add-price-month="0" data-add-price-onetime="1500" data-other-price-divs=".addons">
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-label">op - 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" savingPack">
        <input type="checkbox" name="savingspack" value="savingspack6" data-add-price-month="0" data-add-price-onetime="1500" data-other-price-divs=".addons">
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-label">op - 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.savingPack').on('click touchstart', function(event) {

  var checkbox, allCheckboxes;
  allCheckboxes = $('.savingPack').find('.tile');

  checkbox = $(this).find('.tile');
  checkbox.toggleClass('active');

  var other = allCheckboxes.not(checkbox);
  if (other.hasClass('active')) {
    other.triggerHandler('click');
    other.removeClass('active');
  } else console.log(false);

  event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Isn't that what radio buttons are for? Why can't you use them?

Comment: @lee yes, these checkboxes are optional, if I use radio buttons then user can't deselect. ( and if I forcefully make radio prop false then all other my functionality will be off )

Comment: You could have the option of "None" with your radio buttons...

Comment: @LeeTaylor, actually on click of these checkboxes some complex calculations are done, so i don't have enough room to accomodate anything else at this time.

Comment: i don't have any option of 'none' in my VD - and it takes ages to change the VD in my case.

Comment: VD? Anyway, checking and unchecking check boxes is trivial. Please show your attempt(s)

Comment: added code above ( earlier there was only two checkboxes ) and above code was working fine. Now the checkboxes can be any number. - i have deleted some HTML code to simplify for the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('input[name="savingspack"]').on('click',function(){
   if(this.checked){
      $('.tiles input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
      $(this).prop('checked',true);
   }
});
```